# Do we allow "ask for resource" questions? / Чи ми дозволяємо питання пошуку ресурсів

Tags: discussion

**Питання знімається - обговорення перенесено у [цей пост](https://ukrainian.meta.stackexchange.com/q/40/69).**

As far as I know there are two policies on asking questions that ask for resources like "Good online dictionary" or "Where I can listen to ukrainian online radio with good pronunciation?". Some sites (like Stackoverflow) prohibit asking such questions, while some other allow them.

Unfortunately I cannot give examples of such sites - I just remember that there was a StackOverflow podcast on this topic where this variety of possible policies was discussed.

Personally I think that for such topic as programming that has a big commercial interest in creating online resources, trial and shareware tools, etc., etc. the restriction on resource questions is appropriate.

However for many humanitarian topics and especially for Ukrainian language which has limited number of good resources such questions (and answers) would be valuable.

So I think that we should allow asking such questions, with some restrictions of course: that the resource should be connected to Ukrainian language and that there is no (hidden) promotion or self-promotion of those resources.

Also we can create a community-wiki post which will collect all those useful resources and new questions could be closed as duplicates if a resources are already known. (And, by the way, sometimes a new resources can emerge which are not in the list).

So let's vote below this post - do we allow the questions asking for resources on main site or not.

---

Наскільки мені відомо, на сайтах *.stackexchange.com є дві політики відносно питань щодо пошуку онлайн-ресурсів, наприклад "Порадьте гарний онлайн-словник" або "Де я можу послухати українське онлайн-радіо з гарною вимовою?". Деякі сайти (як Stackoverflow) забороняють такі питання, в той час як інші - дозволяють.

Нажаль, я не можу навести приклади цих сайтів - я пам'ятаю що був Stackoverflow-подкаст присвячений цій темі де розповідалося про існування таких двох політик і чому сайти вибирають дозволити такі питання.

Моя особиста думка така: для тем, (наприклад пов'язаних з программуванням), де є велика комерційна зацікавленність у створенні навчальних ресурсів або навіть програмних компонентів, безкоштовних, тріальних, рекламних і т.і., така заборона виправдана.

Але для багатьох гуманітарних тем (і особливо для української мови), для яких існує небагато якісних ресурсів, такі питання (і відповіді на них) були б дуже корисними.

Отже, моя думка, що такі питання мають бути дозволеними на основному сайті, але звичайно за умови що будуть виконуватися певні обмеження: ресурси повинні бути про українську мову і питання не повинно бути пов'язане з (прихованою) рекламою або саморекламою таких ресурсів.

Також ми можемо створити пост із списом вже відомих якісних ресурсів і тоді питання щодо вже відомих ресурсів можна буде закривати як повторні. (І, доречі, можуть з'являтися нові ресурси, яких ще нема в такому "великому" списку).

Отож, давайте проголосуємо під цим постом - чи ми дозволяємо питання щодо пошуку онлайн-ресурсів на основному сайті, чи ні.

Comment: …І верхній коментар я також пропоную прибрати. SE так не працює, ви не можете задавати правила голосування.

Comment: Можна якось домовитися. Або одразу сказати що можна поставити +  одному варіанту і - іншому. Бо я б не здогадався що можна голосувати двічі.

Comment: Можна і домовитися. Але не можна одноосібно встановлювати правила. Не тому, що ідея погана, а тому, що не існує means of its enforcement.

Comment: Я не встановлюю правила. Я пропоную.

Comment: Питання не треба псувати закресленням через весь текст. Натомість, треба cast your close vote. У даному випадку, позначити його як дублікат того питання, де ведеться обговорення.